# Dado dois IP's é possível verificar se vem da mesma rede?

Tags: python, ip

Estou começando com Python agora e estou desenvolvendo um projeto para achar usuários com múltiplas contas em um determinado site. Os IP's já estão obtidos, mas falta conseguir verificar se, comparando os IP's, dois ou mais IP's venha do mesmo computador. Por exemplo:

Dado os IP's 177.158.xxx.xxx e 177.135.xxx.xxx é possível saber se eles vem do mesmo computador/rede? Se sim, como?

Comment: Sua aplicação vai ser acessada pela internet, LAN, intranet? Deixe mais claro como é quem vai acessar sua aplicação.

Comment: Obrigado por tentar ajudar-me, mas já resolvi o problema. Não consegui fazer o que estava descrito na minha questão, mas sim resolvi de outra maneira. Mais uma vez, obrigado.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

só com o MAC(endereço da placa de rede), que poderia ser possível, ou até mesmo
se o usúario acessar a mesma conta com outros IPs.
Não sei nada sobre programação em Python, mas posso te dizer que quando um usuário acessa um site, aparece tanto o IP, sistema operacional, navegador, etc..

Ex:
Data:06/01/2018

browser:Google Chrome

IP:192.168.0.1

SO:Windows 7

só não sei se o MAC aparece, que seria a solução para o seu problema

Espero ter ajudado :D

Comment: Após algumas pesquisas tomei mais ciência disso e vi que não era possível fazer da maneira que eu queria. Obrigado.